How can I display SSRS 2019 Folders/reports in ASP.NET website after custom authentication
Is there anyway to fetch folders and reports and controls subscription via SSRS 2019 API and then display in Asp.net website. I enabled custom authentication for SSRS2019 report server by following below link
https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample
But now, how do I pass my credentials to an API and fetch reports?
I want to connect to a SSRS2019 API, and after successful authentication, I need to fetch reports and display in an ASP.NET / C# website.
